# Symfony2 jms/i18n-routing-bundle and security

Tags: symfony-2.3

what I'm trying to do :

1. locale in url except for default locale
2. whole pages secured except the login page

[i18n-routing-bundle](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSI18nRoutingBundle)

```
jms_i18n_routing:
  default_locale: %locale%
  locales: %locales%
  #strategy: prefix
  strategy: prefix_except_default
```

Routes

```
arsf_base_default:
  pattern:  /
  defaults: { _controller: ArsfBaseBundle:Default:index }
arsf_base_homepage:
  pattern:  /monit/bysector
  defaults: { _controller: ArsfMonitBundle:BySector:index }
arsf_base_login:
  pattern:  /login
  defaults: { _controller: ArsfBaseBundle:Default:login }
arsf_base_login_check:
  pattern:  /login_check
arsf_base_logout:
  pattern:  /logout
  defaults: { _controller: ArsfBaseBundle:Default:logout }
```

And I tried to configure security.yml as

```
    login:
        pattern:  ^/|[a-z]+/login$
        security: false
        anonymous:  true

    secured_area:
        pattern:    ^.*$
        form_login:
            check_path: arsf_base_login_check
            login_path: arsf_base_login
            default_target_path: arsf_base_homepage
        logout:
            path:   arsf_base_logout
            target: arsf_base_login

access_control:
    - 
      path: ^/|[a-z]+/login$ 
      roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY
    -
      path: ^.*$
      roles: ROLE_USER
```

In this case I get error

```
Unable to find the controller for path "/login_check"
```

So I tried to remove login firewall and configure secured_area with anonymous: ~

In this case all pages are accessibles without authentication and I've not found better solution than make a test in my layout :

```
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body>
    {% if app.user %}
        ...
    {% else %}
        <script>window.location.replace("{{ path('arsf_base_login') }}");</script>
    {% endif %}
</body>
</html>
```

Is there a better way to do ?
What's wrong in my security conf ?

Comment: Hello, nobody to help me ? Does my request lack of information ?